# Server error in '/' Application .asp webforms

Tags: c#, sql, database

I've added to my .asp website a CreateUserWizard with destination page url home. After I'm launching it in Visual Studio 2013, it opens, I register, but, after a long delay after pressing sign up, it shows me this error:

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)

Should I create a database myself or how it can't locate the server?

Answer (score 1):

I think that connection string for database is not correct. Try creating an empty database and add that connection string in web config.

Comment: The thing is that I'm using a database for storing data. Can it be a conflict or something? I see in the web config only the connection string for the database created by myself.

Comment: Update: I've created a blank .asp page with createuserwizard only. Still don't work, same error.

Comment: would be better if you can perhaps share you web.config with me or even better if you can share you code on github or somewhere...

Answer (score 0):

The error is telling you it can't find the database you have specified in your connection string (perhaps a typo or an incorrect details)

[this page](https://www.connectionstrings.com) will help you create the connection string. You will just need your server details

Comment: Thanks, this will really help me. I will try and I will come with updates.